# time complexity of binary search using master theorem and also the recurrence relation of the same

Tags: algorithm, search

What is the master theorem? How is the time complexity of binary search concluded using the theorem? I want to know the exact explanation of this topic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since it is more about algorithms, I believe this question can be placed in StackExchange computer science page. Refer this [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/599158)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master theorem provides a clearcut way to determine the running time of a wide variety of divide and conquer algorithms with big-theta notation (giving a tight upper and lower bound on the worst-case run time). The run time of many divide and conquer algorithms on an input of size n can be expressed with a recurrence equation T(n). Suppose we have that:

- For small enough input, T(n) is constant.
- For large enough input, T(n) = a*T(n/b) + f(n), where *a* is the number of subproblems the algorithm is recursively called on, each subproblem is of size *n/b*, and the total amount of non-recursive overhead is *f(n)*. The non recursive overhead is what the algorithm spends in the divide step and the conquer step.

Now, consider also a critical function: n^(log_b(a)), that is, n to the power of log base b of a. Given the recurrence equation, you can calculated what this is because you know what a and b are.

The master theorem essentially says:

1. If f(n) is polynomially smaller than n^(log_b(a)), then the algorithm runs in time proportional to n^(log_b(a)).
2. If f(n)=n^(log_b(a)), then the algorithm runs in time proportional to n^(log_b(a))*log(n)
3. If f(n) is polynomially larger than n^(log_b(a)), then the algorithm runs in time proportional to f(n).

Note that not all divide and conquer algorithms have run times which can be put in this form for some *a*,*b*, and *f(n)*, but **a lot** of them can - including binary search.

Binary search takes an input of size n, spends a constant amount of non-recursive overhead comparing the middle element to the searched for element, breaks the original input into half, and recursive on only one half of the array. Now plug this into the master theorem with a=1, subproblems of size n/b where b=2, and non-recursive overhead f(n)=1. Calculate the critical function n^(log_b(a))= n^(log_2(1)) = n^0 = 1. So, now we compare f(n)=1 to the critical function n^(log_b(a))=1. They are equal, so we are in case 2 of the master theorem. Hence, the total running time is proportional to n^(log_b(a))*logn=logn.